# Changing negative button color on ListPreference dialog

Tags: android, dialog, themes, android-preferences, listpreference

I have Preference fragment with ListPreference in it.
When I click on it, the color of text for "cancel" negative button in the dialog is not good and I need to change it, and I don't know how.

So far I understand that if I put in my theme:

```
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogStyle</item>
```

That will affect my dialog, but I don't know what to put in style to make my button text change color.
I need to only change the color of that button and nothing else.

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to your `styles.xml`.

Add this style with your button-color:

```
<style name="AlertDialogButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The last step is to add those styles in your base-theme of your app (style which the SettingsFragment takes its style from:

```
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/AlertDialogButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/AlertDialogButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/AlertDialogButton</item>
```